# Kibana. Average number of events per hour per period by hour

Tags: elasticsearch, jenkins, kibana

My company has many developers and a limited number of agents for Jenkins that are used for builds and testing. I need to find out what hours are the most builds stand to a row.
I'm trying to use Kibana for this. But it turns out only to get the information I need only for one day:
[MyVisualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQe0D.png)
And I need to see the period per month, but that in the Visualization on the X-Axis were only hours and the average number of builds per month grouped by hour.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for :P

> http:///view/all/builds